# What are the nuances between the use of 訊く instead of 聞く in the following sentence?

Tags: kanji, nuances, etymology

I know that 訊く is another way to write 聞く, so now I'm curious as to why the author of the book used it here instead of 聞く, which has been used for all previous instances in the book.

> こちらから**訊く**より先に、低く呟くような声が返ってきた。

As I've mentioned in [What is the definition of 凶々?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65968/what-is-the-definition-of-%E5%87%B6%E3%80%85) , I'm wondering if there are any nuances or slightly different meanings when it comes to using different kanji that have the same-ish dictionary definition and how to understand the *why* or to discern the meaning behind the seemingly random different kanji being used in sentences.

For example, what is the difference between

> こちらから**訊く**より先に、低く呟くような声が返ってきた。

and

> こちらから**聞く**より先に、低く呟くような声が返ってきた。

Comment: Looks like you might have mis-typed 低 instead of 訊

Comment: @sazarando thanks for pointing that out, its now fixed.

Comment: 「 **[低]{ひく}くような**声」って？ Are you sure you have copied it correctly?

Comment: Related: [Why are there many kanji that are read and mean the same?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30735/5010) Also, see my answer here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55317/5010

Comment: @Chocolate (Sorry for this very reply) It's the fourth sentence from the right, and yes, I've copied it correctly, as seen in the linked image. https://imgur.com/a/xgQgnYv

Comment: 「低く **[呟]{つぶや}く** ような声が」やん～もお～

Comment: @Chocolate Try refreshing your page.... I had edited it to add the 呟く kanji a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - 訊く is often used to *specifically indicate* that the actor is ***asking a question***
> - 聞く is more *generic* and could *also mean* that the actor only **"hears" or "listens to"** something